# How to use poll() when dealing with multiple file descriptors?

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, polling

I have a program that creates a number of input named pipes for which I must use poll() in order to watch over those pipes and get the information that has been written in them at the time that something has been written in them. I'm very new to polling and I couldn't find many examples that would clearly show how to use poll for multiple file descriptors.

Here is how I wrote the code:

```
char buffer [1024];
size_t count = 0;
ssize_t = bytes;
    while(1)
    {
        int n = poll(pollFd, number_of_pipes, 3000);

        if(n != 0)
        {
             if (n == -1)
             {
                 perror("poll");
                 exit(1);
             }

             for(j = 0; j < number_of_pipes; j++)
             {
                 if(pollFd[j].revents & POLLIN)
                 {
                     //read the written pipe
                     if((bytes = read(fd[j], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)  
                        count += (size_t) bytes;
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```

However, I'm not sure if this the correct way to handle the multiple input pipes while using poll(); since I'm also not sure how to know when the **read** function have reached the end of the file.

Comment: How do you initialize the pollFD array?

Comment: Please copy-and-paste actual compilable code. `ssize_t = bytes;` is a syntax error (the `=` shouldn't be there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks ok, if incomplete (you don't show how you set up the `pollFd` and `fd` arrays).   It does ignore the actual data read, just counting the total amount; for a real program you probably want to do something with the data.

A couple of comments

- If you change it to read from `pollFd[j].fd` instead of `fd[j]`, you don't need the redundant `fd` array -- the descriptors are necessarily all in the `pollFd` array
- You don't check for EOF or errors on read -- if read returns 0 or -1, you should remove that entry from the `pollFd` array and reduce `number_of_pipes`.

Comment: Thank you very much! You had helped me a lot. I was having trouble with the if((bytes = read(fd[j], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) part of the code since if I made an 'else' statement the code would never execute the else after having read the entire pipe. But I found it better to use a while instead of an if 'while((bytes = read(fd[j], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)'. Again thank you very much, you gave me really good points to work with.